# Firebase Error: No Firebase App has been created

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am working on a native app on React Native. Everything was working correctly until i created a page to save user data to the database. At first it was working correctly as intended, i was able to send the information to the database. But when i refreshed the app it show an error saying "No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created -call Firebase App.initializeApp()". I have already initialized it in my App.js, so i deleted the page and error went away. I created the page again and it worked correctly again till i refreshed the app.
Here is my code check it and guide me please.

DataScreen.js

```
import firebase from "firebase";

const userID = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

export default class DataScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    fname: "",
    restaurant: "",
    city: "",
    address: "",
    phone: "",
  };

  handleSave = () => {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref()
      .child("Users")
      .child(userID)
      .set(this.state, function (error) {
        if (error) {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;

          console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);

          Alert.alert("Message :" + errorMessage);
        } else {
          Alert.alert("Information added succesfully");
        }
      })
      .then((ref) => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
      })
      .catch((error) => this.setState({ errorMessage: error.message }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <DataInputs/>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're using a new instance of the firebase app every time the module reloads.

You have to initialize your firebase once and use the instance throughout your app.

`firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase';

try {
   firebase.initializeConfig({ /* Config here* /})
} catch(err) {
   // swallow the error
   console.log(err)
}

/* use this firebase in your project. */
export default firebase;
```